# How do you format date as the following example: 2021-08-17T10:19:02.019Z in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have use PHP to convert a simple datetime from MySQL

`example: 2022-02-21 10:26:27`

to a format like this one:

`2021-08-17T10:19:02.019Z`.

What function and formatting pattern should I use?

Also, could you please help me understand what the `.019Z` stand for?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Using `echo date("c");` results in an output like this one: `2022-02-21T14:14:22+01:00`, which differs form the desired output in the latest part (milliseconds and timezone).

On the other hand, if I do `echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v");` I get an output like the following: `2022-02-21T14:22:24.000`, where I should only be missing the timezone. I am not able to find it in the documentation.

The server isn't on the standard timezone, and I would like not to change it. Is there a way to get it dynamically?

Comment: .019 is milliseconds, and Z means UTC, +00:00 timezone.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I added the answer to your questions in the EDIT section of my request, just before you added this comments. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The format you're looking for is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You can use the defined constants in DateTime object in PHP:

```php
echo $objDateTime->format('c');
echo $objDateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

See also [DateTime formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) in PHP documentation and the [DateTime class itself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: I'm used to use the date() function, using date("c"); shoul be equivalent to $objDateTime->format('c'). But I get this output: 022-02-21T14:22:24+01:00, which differs in the latest parte, about milliseconds and timezone.

Answer (score -2):

DateTime::format -- DateTimeImmutable::format -- DateTimeInterface::format -- date_format — Returns date formatted according to given format

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The problem is, the given format is the part that I'm missing, as explaind in the question